# Why does ruby wrap my extended standard error in an argument error?

Tags: ruby, exception, irb

This seemingly simple code snippet behaves astoundingly:

```
class Nex < StandardError
end

throw Nex.new
```

returns `ArgumentError: uncaught throw #<Nex: Nex>`

Okay, maybe I have to try/catch:

```
begin
  throw Nex.new
rescue Nex
end
```

returns `ArgumentError: uncaught throw #

What about rescuing ArgumentError?

```
begin
  throw Nex.new
rescue ArgumentError => e
  puts e
end
```

returns `uncaught throw #<Nex: Nex>` => nil

What's going on here? I expect to *catch* Nex! It makes no sense that extending a standard error can turn into an ArgumentError, because ArgumentError also extends StandardError.

Comment: Isn't it `raise` instead of throw?

Comment: It might help to read the [Kernel#throw](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-throw) documentation and compare it to [Kernel#raise](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-raise).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ruby `rescue` is for rescuing exceptions (and so shouldn't be used for flow control). `rescue` is paired with `raise` (and its synonym `fail`).

On the other hand (and confusingly if you're coming from Java, C++ or any other language that uses throw to mean "propagate this exception), in Ruby `throw` is paired with `catch` and is a flow control mechanism.

They are similar on the surface, `throw` goes up the call stack looking for a matching `catch`. The thing you throw/catch is very commonly a symbol but it can be an arbitrary object. If there is no matching `catch` then you get an `ArgumentError`.

`throw`/`catch` is faster than raising an exception because in general you don't need to construct a backtrace.

Answer (score 1):

Because in Ruby there are the keywords `raise` and `fail`, which do what you need.

[`throw`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-throw) is a method in the `Kernel` module and works differently. Check the documentation.

Comment: There are no `raise` and `fail` keywords in Ruby.